# Test send email on WSO2 ESB

Tags: soap, wsdl, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I want to send emails from esb to some email address.

In order to do so I uncommented this lines in the axis2.xml file:

```
<transportSender class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender" name="mailto">
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.host">smtp.gmail.com</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.port">587</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.auth">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.user">synapse.demo.0</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.password">mymailpassword</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.from">mymail@gmail.com</parameter>
    </transportSender>
```

and

```
<transportReceiver name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener">
    </transportReceiver>
```

Then I added [this](http://pastebin.com/Xp8iVs7k) proxy to the WSO2 ESB.

Now I want to send an email from ESB to `anymail@gmail.com`.

I was thinking on using SoapUI to do so, so I created a new SOAP project and used the link `https://localhost:9443/services/MailProxy?wsdl` as the `Initial WSDL`.

Now [this](http://s32.postimg.org/9l1ypq13p/asd2safd.png) appears, but now I don't know what code I should enter in order to send the email. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the receiver's mail address like below, in the address endpoint of the proxy service configuration.

```
<send> 
<endpoint> 
<address uri="mailto:anymail@gmail.com"/> 
</endpoint> 
</send>
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that. I just mistiped the email when I copied the code to pastebin. But my difficulty is what to do in ESB in order to send the actual email. When I click on "Test this service" and then "Send" it gives a "Read timed out" error. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Can you see the following message formatter in (enabled) the messageFormatter section of the axis2.xml file?
<messageFormatter contentType="text/plain"
                       class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"/>

According to the provided configurations, if you provide a correct mail address and password, then this should work and If you check the "anymail@gmail.com" mail account, then you should see a mail with "attachment.csv" file attachment and "File Received" subject.Also, if it is not working, send the error logs in ESB carbon logs, after invoking this proxy service.

Comment: Well, apparently I mistyped the email address and that was giving me an error. Now everything is ok, but everytime I try to send a message I get a message on the gmail sender account saying that Google blocked a Login try of an application that doesn't fulfil the security patterns.